# How to run SSIS packages to multiple servers based on environment variables?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I've created a SSIS package that needs to run on multiple different servers (DEV, QA, and PROD). I see that in SQL Server 2019, I can set the package to pass the SERVER_NAME variable which varies based on the environment (dsDev, agQA, agPROD). Those are passed into the SSIS design and set as variables, but they aren't being used anywhere yet. My question is; where do I set those variables in the design so that the SQL Server Agent Job knows which server to run the job in?

Everything in my SSIS design is hardcoded to the DEV server currently.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Environments in your deployment(s) or environmental variables with project variables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For those interested, you need to set up those variables (server and database names) as expression under your connection manager.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).